# git fail to detect "add or delete" conflict attempt to merge instead

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I was attempting to perform a rebase a feature branch today and i got into a very weird behaviour of git.

Basically i have a branch that had conflict with master, once i try to rebase my branch with the new master i got conflict in 2 files, one was pretty "normal" merge conflict, but the other once that i expect to be an "add or delete" conflict, since the file has beeing delete in master was attempted to be merged with another file that have nothing to do with it.

What i expect was:

```
both modified:   file.php
deleted by them:   file.js
```

What i got instead:

```
both modified:   file.php
both modified:   file2.php
```

NOTE: `file2.php` wasn't present in the feature branch.

Any clue of why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be explained by understanding how rebasing works in Git.  The first step in a rebase is to rewind the feature branch and replay the commits from `master` which happened since the most recent common ancestor commit.  Then, the commits you made to feature since that common ancestor are replayed.  But this means that your commits will be on top of the new base from `master`.

If this is confusing you, perhaps a brief diagram would explain it better.  Consider the situation where one commit has been made both to the remote `master` and to your `feature` branch since the common ancestor:

```
master:   ... A -- B
               \
feature:        C
```

The first step of rebasing is to *rewind* your `feature` branch and then replay the commits in `master` since the common ancestor `A`.  This leaves us with:

```
master:   ... A -- B
               \
feature:        B       (commit C not yet applied)
```

The final step is to reapply your commits from `feature` on top of the rebased branch:

```
master:   ... A -- B
               \
feature:        B -- C'
```

Here I have used `C'` rather than just `C`, because technically this is an entirely new commit.

To get to the point, what is happening in a rebase is that your commits are being played on top of a different branch/base.  For this reason, it is totally possible that you could get a conflict with the file `file2.php`, because it could have been present in one of your earlier commits.  And the `master` branch may have also modified this file at the point where the commit(s) were being reapplied.